# I can't scroll a window with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a kind of a calculator which has some windows and in one of them several calculations are displayed, those calculations can be infinite so I need to scroll the window to be able to show all the calculations

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ0P7.jpg)

I've been trying some answers to similar questions in this web, but nothing worked for me. I let you here a piece of my code

```
#Windows building 
    # Adding the window to the Main Frame


    self.pantalla = Text(self.frame, width=50, height=10, background="lightgoldenrod4",
                         cursor="arrow")

    self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.pantalla, orient = VERTICAL)
    self.scroll.pack(side= RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.scroll.config(command=self.pantalla.yview)
    self.pantalla.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)



    # Window colocation
    self.pantalla.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=15, padx=(5, 5), pady=0, sticky='WSNE')
    self.pantalla.grid_propagate(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ScrolledText` widget instead.

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

self.pantalla = ScrolledText(self.frame, width=50, height=10, background="lightgoldenrod4",
                         cursor="arrow")

# Window colocation
self.pantalla.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=15, padx=(5, 5), pady=0, sticky='WSNE')
self.pantalla.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the ScrolledText widget, thanks, but when I tried your answer the text is scrolled but the buttons aren't , maybe it's because the text goes with insert method but the buttons go with place method instead?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see wrong with your code is that you're packing the scrollbar inside the text widget. You shouldn't do that. Instead, the scrollbar should be a sibling (ie: share the same parent) as the text widget.

In your case, I would make the scrollbar and text widget a child of `self.frame`, and then use `pack` to put them both on the screen.

```
self.pantalla = Text(self.frame, width=50, height=10, background="lightgoldenrod4",
                     cursor="arrow")

self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = VERTICAL)
self.scroll.config(command=self.pantalla.yview)
self.pantalla.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)

self.scroll.pack(side= RIGHT,fill=Y)
self.pantalla.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: If I try your answer the window just increases  in size in order  to be able to show all the calculations, what can be the reason?

Comment: @gcb: the code in your question doesn't exhibit that problem. If you don't want the widget to resize, you can give it a fixed size with the `geometry` command. That will force the window to a specific size.

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried your answer again but I still have the same problem, the text can scroll, but not the buttons... is there any way so I can share the whole code with you and, if you want to, help me? Nobody can help me with this problem and I'm stuck

Comment: @gcb: the code in your question doesn't have any buttons. You need to provide a [mcve] that accurately reflects the problem.